# What is the equivalent of WSAEvent in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets

What exactly is `WSAEvent`?

I guess `WSAEvent` is just a number similar to socket descriptor in Linux. So is `WSAEventSelect()` the same as `select()` in Linux.

Comment: I am required to port a Windows application into Linux. I understand the api to create client/server apps in Linux, but in Windows, it has WSAEvent which I don't know where it fits.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question of the title:

The POSIX asynchronous I/O is probably the closed equivalent for overlapped IO of Windows. See [man page of aio(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/aio).

If you want to port a windows application to Linux, then I suggest to use `select()` instead of AIO stuff. `select` is more used and simple to use. After you have done your Linux version with `select()`, you can easily port network parts back to Windows. In general: avoid using `WSAxxxx` stuff when implementing portable programs.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the question, (port Windows application into Linux)
these should get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742219.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741561.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out an event loop, like libev or libevent. As far as I understand, the "event" in WSA is similar to "watcher" in libev, so it should convert without changing the logic a lot.

Answer (score -1):

[This snippet](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/net/base/listen_socket.cc&exact_package=chromium&q=WSAEvent&type=cs&l=253) from [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) source code, should get you started. The "base" library used in Chromium is cross-platform.

Comment: This is the thing with links...if you just link your answer and the link breaks, you have an answer no more...